# AWS CodeCommit slow pull to ec2 instance

Tags: linux, git, amazon-ec2, aws-codecommit

I have large codecommit reporitory (450mb+ 40k+ commits). When I try to pull this repo from scrach to EC2 instance it takes 3-5min, but if I start self-hosted Gitlab in this vpc and try to pull same repo form Gitlab it takes 2-3 time faster.

I added code commit interface com.amazonaws.region.git-codecommit to VPC and AZ. But it doesn't help so much.

Is there some possibility to make it faster without any caches in EC2 instance?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't compare the transfer between two instances within the same VPC, and likely within the same AZ (which means they're probably physically close), to the transfer from an instance to a service like CodeCommit that's hosted "somewhere else" in the AWS infrastructure, even if they're in the same region.
The former will naturally be faster.